# How to debug my PHP validation function?

Tags: php

I am creating a web form for my work which is being validated using PHP. However, when I test the page I keep getting all of my error messages returned without the form being submitted properly when valid information is inputted. The following is a small section of the code (including the HTML sections).

```
<?php
$date =""
$dateerror = ""
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
        $dateerror = "Date is required";
    } else {
        $date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
        $array = explode("/", $date);

        $day = $array[1];
        $month = $array[0];
        $year = $array[2];

        if (!checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
            $dateerror = "Date mustbe in M/D/Y format";
        } else {
            date_default_timezone_set("America/Anchorage");
            $today = strtotime("now");
            if (strtotime($date)>=$today) {
                $date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
            } else {
                $dateerror = "Date is before present day";
            }
        }
    }

<input type="text" size="9" name="date" id="date" required title="Please enter current date"><?php echo $dateerror; ?><br>
```

Again, the PHP code just returns "Date is before present day" even when the date is the current date.

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, show your `checkdate()` function, print out all relevant variable values. (And how is the question about `regex`, btw?)

Comment: `$today` is a current timestamp, including hours, minutes and seconds. But you are comparing it to `$date` which does not have hours, minutes, or seconds, so `strtotime` assumes 00:00:00 which makes it earlier than the current timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to validate a date in PHP, the best way to do it is to use the `DateTime` class, and specifically the [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method.

This call will create a `DateTime` object set to the specified date in the given format, or `false` if it was an invalid date.

So for example:

```
<?php
$input = "05/08/2015";

$test = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $input);
if (!$test) {
    print "You entered an invalid date";
    die;
}

$now = new DateTime();
if ($test < $now) {
    print "Date is before present.";
    die;
}
?>
```

Simple as that. There's no need for regex, or for exploding the input, etc; just a single simple test. And you can also then use the `$test` variable to process the date as well once you've determined that it's valid, since it's a standard DateTime object.

[EDIT] I've added a bit in the code to deal with using the `DateTime` class to handle date comparisons, to give the 'before present' error.

The important point here is that if you have a DateTime object, you need to compare it with another DateTime object; the older `strtotime()` produces a different type of date resource to `DateTime`, and you can't use them together (at least not without converting between them all the time).

Comment: @spundley, when I use this code segment in my form (the first time it gave me an error until i added `date_default_timezone_set("America/Anchorage");` at the beginning of the function) it still returned the error message of "Date is before present day"

Comment: @Dragonman86: Re default timezone: this should really be set in your php.ini or the .htaccess file. Defining it this way in you PHP code should only really be a last resort if you don't have access to either of these files.

Comment: @Dragonman86: Re "before present day" -- you'll need different code for this bit as well. I'll modify the answer to include a bit for this.

Comment: Thank you, this did help and now that section of the total coding is working correctly. I will just have to get the rest of the coding working before I can publish the page. Once again thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

The solution: use `date("M/D/Y")`:

```
$today = strtotime(date("M/D/Y")); // 1432958400
$date = strtotime($_POST["date"]); // user input. 05-30-2015 will yield 1432958400
// the rest of your logic here
```

Here's the code specific solution:

```
<?php
$date =""
$dateerror = ""
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
        $dateerror = "Date is required";
    } else {
        $date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
        $array = explode("/", $date);

        $day = $array[1];
        $month = $array[0];
        $year = $array[2];

        if (!checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
            $dateerror = "Date mustbe in M/D/Y format";
        } else {
            date_default_timezone_set("America/Anchorage");
            $today = strtotime(date("M/D/Y"));
            if (strtotime($date)>=$today) {
                $date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
            } else {
                $dateerror = "Date is before present day";
            }
        }
    }

<input type="text" size="9" name="date" id="date" required title="Please enter current date"><?php echo $dateerror; ?><br>
```

Comment: Why, `strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))`, instead of `time()`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php?

Comment: `time()` is specific to the second. `strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))` is specific to the day. I believe OP is strictly comparing days.

Comment: No, you're just not setting the time. It is midnight still, `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date("Y-m-d")));`

Comment: @chakeda, yes you are right, I am only worried about the day in this form. However, looking over your section of code after the statement "Here's the code specific solution:" it looks like you just re-posted my original code here. I am not sure where you are referring to placing the corrected code.

Comment: @Dragonman86, I changed `strtotime("now")` to `strtotime(date("M/D/Y"))`, because the former is accurate to the second and the latter is accurate to the day.